# change img src with jQuery

Tags: jquery

There are many answers on SO that show how to set an img src  with .attr in jQuery.  For some reason this is not working.

```
<img id="imgMap" style="position:absolute;bottom:7px;right:7px;width:250px;height:250px;" />

<script>
$(function () {   
    $("#imgMap").attr( 'src', 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=41.886456,-87.62325&zoom=14&size=250x250&sensor=false&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C41.886456,-87.62325');
});
</script>
```

But the exact same url put inline in the HTML works fine

```
<img id="imgMap2" runat="server" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=41.886456,-87.62325&zoom=14&size=250x250&sensor=false&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C41.886456,-87.62325" style="position:absolute;bottom:7px;right:7px;width:250px;height:250px;" />
```

Comment: setting 'src' of a div element wont do anything. you should rather use iframe.

Comment: Your code works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/r3vvr/2/

Comment: Works for me : http://jsfiddle.net/kWP6k/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ypDZw/

Comment: there was one letter typo in the url  - I'll accept this , because these other answers are very bad

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine for me,
here is the link: [jquery set attribute value](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/37250691/stackoverflow/jqueryimgattribute.html)